# java math calculation for coordinates of circle given radius of 1.00

Tags: java, math, geometry

In one of my assignments, I am asked to write a program to calculate the (x, y) coordinates of points on a circle of radius 1.0. Display the output of y values for all x values ranging from 1.00 to negative 1.00 by increments of 0.1 and display the output neatly using `printf`, where all the x values are aligned vertically and to the right of all the x values, the y values are aligned vertically like:

```
 x1    y1
1.00  0.00
0.90  0.44
```

I know how to calculate the y values by using the Pythagorean theorem, but I don't know how to display every x and y values neatly by using a loop and formatting it with `printf` Below is my code that I have so far, any help will be greatly appreciated:

```
public class PointsOnACircleV1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    // // create menu

    // create title
    System.out.println("Points on a circle of Radius 1.0");

    // create x1 and y1
    System.out.println("          x1                         y1");

    // create line
    System.out.println("_________________________________________________");

    // // display x values

    // loop?


    // // perform calculation

    // radius
    double radius = 1.00;

    // x value
    double x = 1.00;

    // calculate y value
    double y = Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2);
}

}
```

Comment: Your `y` value is not correct. Anyway, google for loops in java (`for` and `while`, in this case the better would be the former)

Comment: Are you ignoring the fact that for each x(except for 2 points, unless you want to philosophize over if there's really 0 and -0) value in a circle, yields 2 y values?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double radius =  1.00;
    double x  , y ;

    for ( x=-1.0 ; x<=1.0; x+=0.2 ) {
        y = Math.sqrt(radius - Math.pow(x,2)) ;
        System.out.printf("\n" + x +"     "+ y);
    }
}
```

The code within loop you can adjust them according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class PointsOnACircleV1
 {
  public static void main (String [] args)
{
    double r = 1; //radius initialized to one

    double x = 1; // x coordinate initialized to one, could be anything
    double y = 0.0; // y coordinate is dependent so left at 0.

    //output
    System.out.println("\tPoints on a Circle of Radius 1.0"); 
    System.out.printf("\t%6s%6s%12s%7s\n", "x1", "y1", "x1", "y2");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

    //for loop to decrement values from the initialized x coordinate to the 
    //end of the diameter, radius is 1 so diameter is 2 so 1 to -1.
    for(x = 1; x >= -1; x -= .1)
    {
        y = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,2) - Math.pow(x,2)); //pythagorean theorem to achieve y value.
        System.out.printf("\t%6.2f%7.2f%12.2f%8.2f\n", x, y, x, -y); //output, -y to get values
        //for the other 1/2 of the circle
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it would be better if you add some explanation about the code as well ( not specifically line by line comments but a brief description would have been sufficient )

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=100; i>=-100; i-=10) {
    x = i/100.0;
    //do stuff
    System.out.print("\t%.2f\t%.2f", x, y);
}
```

That should get you started.  If you don't understand the part within the parenthesis of the `System.out.print` statement, I suggest you look up what `System.out.print` does, look up `format specifiers`, and look up `escape characters`.  Then you should be all set.

Comment: I think you'll get played by floating point representations here. I think looping from 0 to 19 is better, and mapping it to the corresponding x value.

Comment: That's pretty good actually. But why not `10, -10 and -1`. with `/10.0`. just take a single 0 off of everything. But it's the same thing. +1

Comment: Only because he specified his double should be `1.00`.  If I felt the hundreds place were significant, I'd do it this way.